# Import hash functions into Lazy Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I import hash functions into lazy Racket?

So far I have the following:

```
#lang lazy
(require (only-in racket/base
              hash
              hash-set))
```

and I get the following error:

```
only-in: bad module path in: (only-in racket/base hash hash-set)
```

Where am I going wrong? What would be the correct module path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what version of Racket you're using?  I can't reproduce your error under Racket 5.3: when I try it, your code does what you expect.

Comment: 5.1.3. Just updated to 5.3 and now it works like a charm. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To explain, the implementation of Lazy Racket was an old one, based on the "MzScheme" which is now a compatibility language.  In v5.3 it was modernized and is more in line with the usual `racket` language.